# kotlin flow, use .conflate() with .collect {}, or .collectLatest()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

In an android project, it has one property `token` which could be updated from two remote sources. The expected behavior is to process the last update, or as long as it is not same as the previous one.

Maybe there is better solution suites for this use case, but here is what I try to use (still learning the Flow).

One way is to use the `.distinctUntilChanged()` and `.collectLatest()` together:

```
object TokenManager {
    private val tokenFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    // Expose the flow that merges both sources and keeps distinct values
    val combinedTokenFlow = tokenFlow
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .catch { Log.e("TokenManager", "Failed to get token", it) }

    fun updateToken(token: String?) {
        tokenFlow.tryEmit(token)
    }
}

// from source one, which is a service running and listen to the update
class TokenListenerService : TokenService() {
    override fun onTokenUpdate(s: String) {
        // let the flow emit update
        TokenManager.updateToken(s)
    }
}

// another source emit the token change
    fun init() {
        // Set up the token listener
        val tokenListener = OnCompleteListener<String?> { token ->
            // let the flow emit update
            TokenManager.updateToken(token)
        }

        // Register the token listener
        Messaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(tokenListener)

        // Start observing the token updates on the flow
        startObservingToken()
    }

    fun startObservingToken() {
        launch {
            TokenManager.combinedTokenFlow //update emit from either source should come to here
                .collectLatest { token -> //use .collectLatest
    
                 // do update the token
                
            }
        }
    }
```

or should it use `.distinctUntilChanged()` and `.conflate()` and `.collect{}`

```
object TokenManager {
    private val tokenFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    // Expose the flow that merges both sources and keeps distinct values
    val combinedTokenFlow = tokenFlow
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .conflate() // get the latest one
            .catch { Log.e("TokenManager", "Failed to get token", it) }

    fun updateToken(token: String?) {
        tokenFlow.tryEmit(token)
    }
}

and 

    fun startObservingToken() {
        launch {
            TokenManager.combinedTokenFlow //update emit from either source should come to here
                .collect { token -> // use .collect
    
                 // do update the token
                
            }
        }
    }
```

**update:**
Thanks @Tenfour04 comment. Here is the modified version.

```
interface TokenProvider {
    val combinedTokenFlow: Flow<String?>
    fun updateToken(token: String?)
}

class TokenManager : TokenProvider {
    private val _tokenFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    // Expose the flow that merges both sources and keeps distinct values
    override val combinedTokenFlow: Flow<String?>
        get() = _tokenFlow

    // Function to update the token
    override fun updateToken(token: String?) {
        _tokenFlow. tryEmit(token)
    }
}

val tokenProvider: TokenProvider = TokenManager()

// from source one, which is a service running and listen to the update
class TokenListenerService : TokenService() {
    override fun onTokenUpdate(s: String) {
        // let the flow emit update
        TokenManager.updateToken(s)
    }
}

class NonUiModule : CoroutineScope {
    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default + job

    fun init() {
        // Set up the token listener
        val tokenListener = OnCompleteListener<String?> { token ->
            // let the flow emit update
            TokenManager.updateToken(token)
        }

        // Register the token listener
        
  Messaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(tokenListener)

        // Start observing the token updates on the flow
        startObservingToken()
    }

    fun startObservingToken() {
        launch {
            TokenManager.combinedTokenFlow //update emit from either source should come to here
                .catch { Log.e("NonUiModule", "Failed to get token", it) }
                .collect { token -> // use .collect
    
                 doProcessUpdate(token)
                
            }
        }
    }

    // ... other functions ...
}
```

Not sure how does the StateFlow decide which emit is the latest (since the update may come in fro different source at anytime).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call `conflate()` or `distinctUntilChanged()` on a `StateFlow` because it already has both of these behaviors built in. Both of these operators are mentioned as built-in behaviors in the [StateFlow documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/).

`collect()` vs. `collectLatest()` depends on your needs. Use the latter if you want to abandon whatever you were doing with the previous token if a new one arrives while you were doing something with it. But note that your `collectLatest` lambda has to [cooperate with cancellation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) for this to actually result in different behavior.

I'm not sure if this is your intended behavior or not, but `combinedTokenFlow` is a cold Flow, so your logging in the `catch` operator will only occur when there is currently a collector, and it will be repeated for every simultaneous collector.

However, in the current setup, there is no possible source of exceptions for the `catch` block to catch unless there is something fundamentally broken in the Kotlin coroutines library.

From a design standpoint, using an `object` for this makes it difficult to unit test your app. You might consider making it implement an interface or two (one for exposing the output, one for exposing a way to publish to it) that you inject where it's used.

Comment: thanks! It has only one collector. `catch` block is for catch the exception from parsing the update token data (currently there is a simple tryEmit(data),it may need to do something more on the data there). I updated it to use `collect{}`. The intended behavior is to call doProcessUpdate(token) once on the latest emit if there are multiple updates from different sources. Not sure if there is control on the threshold to decide when the emit is considered the latest one?  Another question I read that StateFlow is `hot` flow, why do you think the `combinedTokenFlow` is a cold Flow?

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand the intended behavior. With `collect` or `collectLatest`, the same thing can happen, where you could theoretically miss some intermediate emissions while collecting one that is now outdated, but you will always get one more collect call for the most recent value if at least one emission happened while the previous one was being collected. The difference between these is that `collectLatest` can exit early to jump ahead to the latest if it knows it is now working on an outdated emission. But it can only do that at a suspend call or `if(isActive)` check.

Comment: When you use a flow operator on a hot flow, it produces a cold downstream flow. This cold flow will internally start a collection from the hot flow each and every time it is collected. Like any cold flow it is passive about the downstream stuff it is doing until it's collected. The upstream flow remains hot.

Comment: The other potential problem with how you're catching is that once a single exception is thrown, your `combinedTokenFlow` will never emit again. Not sure if that was your intent either. Also, throwing an exception parsing your token won't make your MutableStateFlow throw since you would be throwing before emitting.  It would be the `updateToken()` function that throws. I can't think how it would be possible to make a MutableStateFlow throw.

Comment: Thanks! will look at the retry() or retryWhen() for the catch(). We want the combinedTokenFlow be alive as the app, and thought using the catch() will catch the exception and let the combinedTokenFlow continue emit.

Comment: Think about the execution order of the code. Any throwing that occurs while parsing happens before `tryEmit()` so the flow never knows anything about the failure.